# Inserting UNICODE into sqlite3

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I am trying to read a file, parse the data using python 2.7, and import the data into sqlite3. However, I'm running into a problem when inserting the data. After I parse a line from the file, the é in my string is replaced with \xe9. After I split the line from my file, I want a list that contains [73,'Misérables, Les'] but instead I'm getting [73,'Mis\xe9rables, Les'] which is screwing up the SQL INSERT statement. How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import sqlite3
line = '73::Misérables, Les'.decode('latin-1')
vals = line.split("::")

con = sqlite3.connect('myDb.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie")
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE movie (id INT, title TEXT)')
sql = 'INSERT INTO movie VALUES (?,?)'
cur.execute(sql,tuple(vals))

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM movie')
for record in cur:
    print record
```

Comment: Both lists are exactly the same.

Comment: Also, `line = u'73::Misérables, Les'`.

Comment: Why are you using the ancient Python 2? A bunch of things changed for the better with Python 3, where strings are by default Unicode-capable, for example.

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL INSERT statement be: INSERT INTO movie Values (73,'Misérables, Les') and not INSERT INTO movie Values (73,'Mis\xe9rables, Les')

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html has some information about this.  search for text_factory.

Answer (score 0):

Your program inserts data into the db perfectly. It subsequently retrieves the correct data. Your problem is when you display the result.

When you print a tuple, the system displays the `repr()` of each item, not the `str()` of each item. Thus you see `\xe9` instead of `é` in the output.

To get what you want, try replacing the loop at the end of your program:

```
for record in cur:
    print record[0], record[1]
```